# jQuery get all ids on page

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get an array consisting of all id's on a page with jQuery?

Answer (score 21):

You could do this:

```
var ids = new Array();
$('[id]').each(function() { //Get elements that have an id=
  ids.push($(this).attr("id")); //add id to array
});
//do something with ids array
```

One note I saw testing this, the FireBug console counts as one, if that's enabled just be aware.

Comment: Re: Firebug - `$('body [id]')` might be a better option, then, if one can be certain that we don't want `head` elements or the like.

Answer (score 9):

```
var ids = $('*[id]').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

> The .map() method is particularly
>   useful for getting or setting the
>   value of a collection of elements.

http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: This is the sort of thing where to some it's much cleaner, and to those who can't wrap their head around it much uglier.

Answer (score 7):

I think this would work

```
var array = [];
$("*").each(function(){
    if(this.id) array.push(this.id);
});
```