# How do I get all the ID's of sections in a post?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

is there a way to get the ID's in a wordpress post content? For an example, I have this structure in my post_content():

```
get_header()

<div class="main-content">
  <section id="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="projects">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="contacts">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

get_footer()
```

So everything in `.main-content` is the `post_content()`. What I need is to get `#jumbotron`, `#about`, `#projects` and `#contacts` and print that amount of li with foreach.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#jumbotron">Jumbotron</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Jumbotron</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects">Jumbotron</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Jumbotron</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is that even possible? I tried searching for a solution, but can't find something from the wordpress api that does that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get all ids on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367286/jquery-get-all-ids-on-page)

Comment: Others have indicated how to do this in jQuery. If you need to do it in PHP, look at [the DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 0):

I will certainly do it with jQuery. Multiple solutions are available:

```
$('.main-content').children()
```

or

```
$('.main-content > *')
```

Comment: I've kind of thought of that but I don't know how to pass the values I get to php to make an unordered list? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After all I did this with jQuery. The code is in my custom scripts JS file and I've created a container #uList in my php template file.

```
var IDs = $(".main-content section[id]") 
  .map(function() { return this.id; })
  .get(); 

$listSelector = $("#uList")
  $.each(IDs, function(i, obj) {
    $listSelector.append("<li><a href=#"+obj+">"+obj+"</a></li>")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just gather the appropriate elements into a JQuery object, then loop through the object and build up the output you want:

```js
let results = "<ul>";
$(".main-content > section[id]").each((i,el)=>{ 
  results += "<li><a href='#" + el.id + "'>" + el.id + "</a></li>";
});

$(document.body).append(results + "</ul>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
  <section id="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="projects">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="contacts">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOME CONTENT !-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```